# Programmatically displaying HTML element titles

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a javascript way to display or hide element title (defined as an html attribute), as if the mouse was hovering above said dom element, without actually involving the mouse?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The native UI tooltips? No. If you make your own tooltips in JS? Sure.

Comment: This is completely contrary to how the user expects a UI to behave. Why on earth would you want to do this?

Comment: Predicting what the user expects from UI is a rather complex thing, isn't it? Tooltips are situational suggestions, and user input (situation) is not limited to mouse events. Specifically, when user is typing in a search field that has no visual submit button, we could suggest him to press 'Enter' when ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with native tooltips/titles. But there are jQuery plugins like [this](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/) which let you cutomize and control them.

Comment: Except you need to use jQuery, which he didn't mention he was, and then use a plugin along with it.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'm aware of that kind of solution, yet was curious about the native tooltips.

Comment: He didn't mention this, hence my answer was "not with native titles". But jQuery is nothing than a javascript library. Of course he could build his own library to show/hide divs, but why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

I would use an absolutely positioned DIV that looks like the native tooltip and contains the same text as an alternative. It should be fairly trivial to loop through all elements and create a DIV for each one that has a title attribute.

Very little hassle and no JavaScript plugins required.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a tooltip layout (div with border) yourself, and show it when you want with jQuery. You can select a link element with a title like this:

```
a[title] {}
```